# how can i capture multiple form inputs and save in an array

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
<template name="uploadTicket">
    <div class="row">
       <h3> Upload Ticket</h3>
        <form class="ticket-form col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="name">Event Name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="location" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="location">Location</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <input id="date" type="date" class="validate">
                    <label for="date"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <textarea id="description" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                    <label for="Description">Description</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s6">
                    <h5>More Price Fields</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col s6">
                    <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red" id="addField"><i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i></a>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">

                <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <input name="priceClass[]" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="priceClass[]">Class</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <input name="priceAmount[]" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="priceAmount[]">Price</label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <h6>Input Price Classes and Amounts.</h6>
                </div>
                </div>

                <br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div >
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is my Template

```
Template.uploadTicket.events({
    'click #addField': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var max_fields = 10;
        var wrapper = $(".wrapper");
        var add_button = $(".addField");
        var x = 1;


        if (x < max_fields)
        {
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append(' <div class="row"> <div class="input-field col s4"> <input name="priceClass[]" type="text" class="validate"> <label for="priceClass[]">Class</label> </div> <div class="input-field col s4"> <input name="priceAmount[]" type="text" class="validate"> <label for="priceAmount[]">Price</label> </div>  <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red" id="removeField"><i class="mdi mdi-minus"></i></a></div> <br>'); //add input box

        }
       $(wrapper).on("click","#removeField", function(e)
       { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    }


});
```

This is my JavaScript for that template. I am giving the user option to add multiple fields so that they can have different classes for prices. Like gold class for a certain amount, VIP for another amount ,regular for another amount and so on. I am having a problem with how to get those input values when submitting the values and saving them into an array.

Comment: do you want to save the values to an array inside your event and pass it to your server or do you want to pass the values to your method in the server and save inside an array there?

Comment: i would like to pass the values to a method in my server and save it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use jquery to loop through your inputs and send their values into an empty array. Then take the array with data and send it to your collection.

```
let valueStore = [];
console.log(valueStore) // an empty array

$('.input-field input').each(function(){
    if (this.value != ''){
        valueStore.push(this.value)
    }
})

console.log(valueStore) // will have your values.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery-Selectors to get all Input Fields. You allready gave them a class. After that you can extract all necessary information into your array.
The JQuery-Selector should look something like:

```
$('.input-field')
```

Use a forEach loop to get every selected element.